# How can I use this condition outside click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I write this code:

```js
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll('ul').toggleClass('closed');
  if ($(this).parent().next('ul') != true) {
    $(this).prev().removeClass('ion-ios-plus-outline');
    $(this).prev().addClass('ion-ios-minus-outline');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <!-- First level -->
  <li class="branch">
    <!-- btn -->
    <div class="d-flex justfiy-content-between">
      <i class="ion-ios-plus-outline ml-2"></i>
      <span class="toggler ml-3">لول اول</span>
      <span class="btns d-flex">
        <a class="bg-danger" href="">
            <i class="ion-trash-b"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="bg-info mr-2" href="">
            <i class="ion-edit"></i>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <!-- Second level -->
    <ul class="closed">

      <li class="branch">

        <!-- btn -->
        <div class="d-flex justfiy-content-between">
          <i class="ion-ios-plus-outline ml-2"></i>
          <span class="toggler ml-3">لول دوم</span>
          <span class="btns d-flex">
            <a class="bg-danger" href="">
                <i class="ion-trash-b"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="bg-info mr-2" href="">
                <i class="ion-edit"></i>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>

      </li>

    </ul>

  </li>

  <!-- First level -->
  <li class="branch">

    <!-- btn -->
    <div class="d-flex justfiy-content-between">
      <i class="ion-ios-plus-outline ml-2"></i>
      <span class="toggler ml-3">لول اول</span>
      <span class="btns d-flex">
        <a class="bg-danger" href="">
            <i class="ion-trash-b"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="bg-info mr-2" href="">
            <i class="ion-edit"></i>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>

  </li>

</ul>
```

I have a condition in this click function, it works nice. but it just works when I click on that button, but I want this condition to work outside this click function!

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Add your html as well.

Comment: @Luca I think because I don't know how to use $(this) in a condition  outside a function

Comment: $(this) is just $('.toggler')

Comment: @RRK I just add **HTML** code

Comment: @Luca when I write `$('.toggler')`, it checks the `.toggler`s all together but i want them to be checked separated from each other

Comment: forEach? also, dont add the code as an answer, add it as an edit

Comment: @Luca this is the source code in codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/gilasweb/pen/vdLQWB)

Comment: @Luca I don't know how to use **forEach**

Comment: If you google "js forEach" you'll find several sites with information about it